# Segfault inserting into linked list of customers

Tags: c, linked-list, stack

I want to create a stack but I want to keep the head pointer like linked list implementation. Which I mean go head to end opposite stacks.

```
void insertCustomer(CustomerPtr *headPtr, int id, char name[20], char surname[20]){

    CustomerPtr newPtr = (CustomerPtr)malloc(sizeof(Customer));
    newPtr->customerId = id;
    strcpy(newPtr->customerName, name);
    strcpy(newPtr->customerSurname, surname); 
    CustomerPtr previousPtr, currentPtr;
    previousPtr = NULL;
    currentPtr = *headPtr;
    while(currentPtr != NULL){
        previousPtr = currentPtr;
        currentPtr = currentPtr->next; 
    }
    if(previousPtr == NULL){  
        *headPtr = newPtr;
    } else{
        previousPtr->next = newPtr;
    } 
    
}
```

I'm getting a segmentation fault.

Comment: but ı get a segmentation fault

Comment: `strcpy(newPtr->customerName, name);` may be the cause of Segmentation fault if `customerName` is `char*`.

Comment: @berkay_K It seems this "Which I mean go head to end opposite stacks." does not make a sense. If you want to implement a stack then new nodes ,must be placed in the beginning of the list.

Answer (score 1):

It seem you forgot to initialize `newPtr->next`. The initial value of region allocated via `malloc()` is indeterminate and using the indeterminate value invokes *undefined behavior*.

```
void insertCustomer(CustomerPtr *headPtr, int id, char name[20], char surname[20]){

    CustomerPtr newPtr = (CustomerPtr)malloc(sizeof(Customer));
    newPtr->customerId = id;
    strcpy(newPtr->customerName, name);
    strcpy(newPtr->customerSurname, surname); 
    newPtr->next = NULL; /* add this */
    CustomerPtr previousPtr, currentPtr;
   /* ... */
```

Comment: The question states it's trying to implement a stack, so insert should insert at the front, not at the end.

Comment: @rcgldr You should ask this as a question in a comment to the author question.

Comment: The first few words of the question are "I want to create a stack ...".

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to implement a stack using a linked list, then insert|push needs to insert the new node at the beginning of the list, rather than append it to the end of the list, and remove|pop needs to remove the first node of the list. Something like this for insert:

```
    CustomerPtr newPtr = (CustomerPtr)malloc(sizeof(Customer));
    newPtr->customerId = id;
    strcpy(newPtr->customerName, name);
    strcpy(newPtr->customerSurname, surname); 
    newPtr->next = *headPtr;
    *headPtr = newPtr;
```